# Format to numbers entered using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The case goes like this I have 4 textbox the dynamic is the following textbox1 + textbox2 + textbox 3 = textbox4.
When entering the numbers in the textbox, I would like to give it the following format:

NOW: 123456789
WANTED: 123,456,789.00

```js
function agregar_numero() {

  var TextBox1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtremubruta").value);
  var TextBox2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtotrosingresos").value);
  var TextBox3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtremubrutamensual").value);
  var result = TextBox1 + TextBox2 + TextBox3;

  document.getElementById("TxtInfoPatriTotal").value = result;
}
```

```html
<form runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtremubruta" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero()"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtotrosingresos" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero()"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtremubrutamensual" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px" onkeyup="agregar_numero()"></asp:TextBox>
  <br> Total
  <br>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtInfoPatriTotal" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxBorder" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>

</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use toLocaleString method here's the code:

```
var num = 123456789;
num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) // "123,456,789.00"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This may Helps:

```
function addComma(txt) {
txt.value = txt.value.replace(",", "").replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, "$1,$2");
}
```